# Nested list of list to dictionary

Tags: python

There are many examples how to convert a simple nested list do dictionary but how do I iterate over a data structure like this

```
bookings = [['3473', '2021-04-22 14:00'], ['3633', '2021-04-20 15:00'], ['3633', '2021-04-21 11:00']]
```

to this:

```
  obj =  {
                    'Date': '2021-04-22 14:00',
                    'ID': '3473'
                }
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: `[{"ID": id, "Date": date} for id, date in bookings]` is a nice oneliner to convert bookings to a list of dictionary objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over list and make dictionaries.

```
for e in bookings:
    obj = dict()
    obj['id'] = e[0]
    obj['date'] = e[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
reformed_bookings=[]
for item in bookings:
    obj = {}
    obj['id']=e[0]
    obj['date']=e[1]
    ...
    ...
    reformed_bookings.append(obj)
```